# Cannot compile Qt from source using nmake install

Tags: qt, compilation, nmake

I am trying to compile Qt5.7 from source according to [this tutorial](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-building.html). I have created `qt5vars.cmd` file:

```
cd "C:\Qt_all\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.0"
CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
SET _ROOT="C:\Qt_all\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.0"
SET PATH=%_ROOT%\qtbase\bin;%_ROOT%\gnuwin32\bin;%PATH%
SET QMAKESPEC=win32-msvc2015
SET _ROOT=
```

I open it with `cmd`:

```
C:\Qt_all\qt5vars.cmd
```

after that in `cmd`:

```
configure -debug-and-release -opensource -platform win32-msvc2015 -nomake examples -nomake tests
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\nmake"
```

In that case everything works but the Qt binaries are compiled into 'source code' folder. Now I want to compile into another folder. I completely deleted the 'source code' folder (with compiled binaries) and copy pure source code' folder. After that  in `cmd`:

```
C:\Qt_all\qt5vars.cmd
configure -debug-and-release -opensource -platform win32-msvc2015 -nomake examples -nomake tests -prefix "C:\Qt_all\Kits\Qt5.7MSVC2015_64bit"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\nmake" install
```

And that gives an error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file "C:\Qt_all\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.0\qtbase\lib\qtpcred.lib"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to execute `nmake` and only then `nmake install`. You also probably want to use `jom -j%NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%`, not nmake, to speed things up. Jom comes with Qt Creator, you can also get it from [here](https://wiki.qt.io/Jom).